# MapKit Not Showing Location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I've implemented MapKit into my Swift app and everything runs properly and when I run the app it shows a map. However, it's an overview of the United States and not where I want it to be. 
I've imported the MapKit into ViewController and connected the MapView to the ViewController via an IBOutlet, however it's not working.
I didn't put the code in the viewDidLoad because the app crashed every time. Rather, I made a function and that seemed to do the trick. This is all of the code that I've got going for this map:

```
func mapMexico()
    {
        let lat:CLLocationDegrees = 20.648097
        let long:CLLocationDegrees = -105.235168

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: longDelta)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: When It crashed. What did it say?

Comment: use this:  self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true)

Comment: When it crashed it said "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0X0).

Comment: I tried the TrackingMode, but that way that you do it, it doesn't use the region constant, thus, there is no coordinates or span. Where would I call region?